# Facebook Instant Game IAP error: {code: "UNKNOWN", message: "Product not purchaseable"}

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I am developing a game for a client and we are now testing payments / purchasing.

So inside the In-App Purchase set-up page, I've:
1.) added a Dev account to the Testers list
2.) Created a product

My code looks like this:

```
let supportedAPIs:any = FBInstant.getSupportedAPIs();
if(supportedAPIs.includes('payments.purchaseAsync'))
{
    console.log('payments supported...');

    FBInstant.payments.onReady(() => {
        console.log('payments ready...');

        FBInstant.payments.purchaseAsync({
            productID: 'my_temp_prod'
        }).then((purchase) => {
            console.log(purchase);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

I tried to run it on Android and it showed me this once:

[image]

After clicking "OK", it did not show any payment dialog, and I could never get a payment dialog to appear on Android.

I then tried to test it on the desktop browser version and the code simply results in a `{code: "UNKNOWN", message: "Product not purchaseable"}` error.

I am still able to see "payments supported" and "payments ready" logged out so I know that at least that part is working, but I cannot get a test dialog to appear.

Are we missing anything? We already have a payment account setup too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out you have to use `consumePurchaseAsync` after a successful purchase. You can also use `getPurchasesAsync` to check if there are any remaining purchases left that need to be fullfilled.

My bad, I thought purchases for instant games worked liked normal FB games (you didn't have to "consume" products there). For anyone who may be lost, I hope this helps.